# Is there any point in using __attribute__((noinline)) in a source file (not header file)?

Tags: c++, c

Some programmers at my company have started sprinkling `__attribute__((noinline))` in methods all over our code, in both header and source files. We do ***not*** use whole-program optimization. And in the vast majority of the cases I'm seeing, these methods are not calling other methods in the same source file ("translation unit"); the only callers of these "noinline" methods are (in most cases) methods in other source files.

I want to make a point that these `__attribute__((noinline))` attribute markers are not doing anything and only clutter our code, but before I do that I just want to verify that I'm right:

### Is there any benefit to marking a method "noinline" if its definition (code body) is...

- in a source (.c or .cpp) file
- not called by any other methods in that source file
- and whole program optimization is ***not*** being used

## ...?

I.e., in the absence of whole-program optimization, could a compiler+linker even inline a method defined as such (above bullet points) anyway?

Comment: It sounds like nonsense. Regardless of their motivation, anyone typing out `__attribute__((anything))` ought to explain why in comments. The main reason why you'd use `__attribute__((noinline))` apart from debugging/benchmarking purposes etc) is to perform manual code size over execution speed optimizations. Which is odd and rather senseless under the conditions you mention. It _could_ be debugging left-overs. As for if a compiler could inline a function with no optimization settings being present, that's all compiler-specific behavior. Most compilers don't, but no guarantees.

Comment: Is your question for "C" or "C++"? Anyway the only reason I can think of is to limit the size of the generated code (at the cost of extra calls). So it is a tradeof that might make sense for firmware (small devices). But it seems like premature optimization if it is important it should be managed centrally (ask your architect)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I suppose I was stretching the truth in saying "all over our code". The main place I'm seeing this is in methods related to exception handling (CPU exceptions, not C++ exceptions), where we want to capture a stack backtrace for later analysis. The reasoning is that if methods are inlined, they won't show up in the stack backtrace. So the reasoning makes sense from that standpoint; it's just that I don't think the attribute tags are necessary anyway since the methods are being defined in a source file, not in the header file that's #included by other translation units.

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that a function won't be inlined even if defined in a separate TU. It's just about how smart the compiler is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any benefit to marking a method "noinline" if its definition
> (code body) is...
>
> - in a source (.c or .cpp) file
> - not called by any other methods in that source file
> - and whole program optimization is not being used
>
> ...?

The position of the attribute on the function / method definition instead of on a non-definition declaration is not necessarily relevant in the particular case of a `noinline` attribute, because in order for inlining to be performed, some form of the function's definition (which bears the attribute) must be available.

Certainly the function won't be inlined into any other functions in the same translation unit if no other functions in that unit call it in the first place, directly or indirectly.

The "whole program optimization is not being used" seems to be an attempt to stipulate that the function in question cannot be inlined into any other functions, either.  In that case, the `noinline` attribute is, **by assumption**, unnecessary to prevent inlining of that function.

> I.e., in the absence of whole-program optimization, could a
> compiler+linker even inline a method defined as such (above bullet
> points) anyway?

This seems to be a question of semantics.  I would categorize any optimization that crosses translation-unit boundaries as a "whole-program optimization".  In that sense, then, no, a build process that does not perform any whole-program optimization will not perform the specific whole-program optimization of inlining a function from one TU into a function from a different TU.

Since you have not specified any details of your compilation procedure, we cannot speak to whether it is really true in your particular case that whole program optimzation is not being used, in the sense described above.

---

However, whether the attribute is necessary to prevent inlining of functions in your current code base is not the only consideration relevant to the "Is there any benefit?" question.  Consider:

- Whether the attribute is necessary to prevent inlining or not, it is effective at *communicating the intent* that the function should not be inlined.
- In the event that your analysis of the code is wrong, or the code changes so that it no longer applies, the `noinline` attributes will provide for the desired inlining-suppression behavior.

Both of these are reminiscent of the nature and (proper) usage of assertions.  If an assertion in my program ever triggers then that means a situation has arisen that I believed could not happen and assumed would not happen.  Are assertions then just wasteful code?  No, certainly not.  They serve a documentary purpose (often supplemented with explanatory code comments), an error detection purpose, and often a failsafe purpose.  Similar can be said of use of `noinline` under the circumstances you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Inlining can still happen within a source file. If a function is called after its definition, the compiler could inline it. So the attribute would prevent that.

Therefore, this attribute can still have useful effects in source files, to the extent that you need to turn off inlining.

Comment: Yes.  However, the question specifies that the OP is asking about methods that are not called by any other methods in the same source file.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: And what happens when someone decides to change the implementation of a function so that it calls another? To the extent that non-inlining is important, this is just basic defensive coding: ensure that the problem never happens.

Comment: I'm just saying that this answer describes a circumstance that is explicitly excluded by the question.  Whether the question *should* exclude it is a different consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the merits (of using `noinline` or not), I would use macros rather than peppering `__attribute__((noinline))` everywhere.

And, the compiler can disable inlining via the command line (see below).

---

In my code, I sometimes want a function [usually defined in a `.h` file] that will *always* be inlined:

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
```

That's relatively verbose [and error prone], so I define:

```
#define inline_always static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
```

---

I'm not a fan of the compiler deciding the inlining of a function for me, so I disable it from the command line:

```
-fno-inline-small-functions -fno-inline-functions-called-once -fno-inline-functions
```

That might be a safer/better alternative than changing function prototypes.

---

There *is* some merit to *not* inlining functions that have *not* been explicitly marked as `inline`.

For debugging and breakpoints.

The compiler's heuristic fails to produce the best code:

1. It inlines something that provides little benefit from the inlining vs. the function call overhead.
2. The inlining seems good to the compiler but the *calling* function's code is sub-optimal because it causes additional register pressure requiring that the registers be spilled [to the stack] more often.

For debug, we can compile with `-O0` to disable compiler inlining of functions.

But, sometimes, we need to be able to put a [`gdb`] breakpoint on a function in code that has been compiled *with* optimization.
If the function has been [auto] inlined, this won't work [too well].

So, either use `-fno-inline` et. al. or apply the macro to key functions as in:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_NOINLINE
#define noinline_debug      __attribute__((noinline))
#else
#define noinline_debug      /**/
#endif
```

---

Note that the Linux kernel uses such macros:

```
#define noinline __attribute__((noinline))
#define __always_inline inline __attribute__((__always_inline__))
```

This is useful in case a given compiler does not support a particular attribute:

```
#if __has_attribute(__nonstring__)
# define __nonstring                    __attribute__((__nonstring__))
#else
# define __nonstring
#endif
```

Comment: `__has_attribute` itself [is a GCCism](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/_005f_005fhas_005fattribute.html)